# Is $w \in \operatorname{span}(M)$? And, what is the set $\operatorname{span}(M)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the following matrix $M$:
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
0.8147 & 0.9134 & 0.2785 & 0.9649 & 0.9572 \\
0.9058 & 0.6324 & 0.5469 & 0.1576 & 0.4854 \\
0.1270 & 0.0975 & 0.9575 & 0.9706 & 0.8003
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**rank(M) = 3**

Now, I want to consider vector $\mathbf{w}$:
$$
\mathbf{w} = \begin{bmatrix}
-0.1 \\
-0.3 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

**(a) Is $w \in \operatorname{span}(M)$? Provide arguments.
(b) And identify the set $\operatorname{span}(M)$. Provide arguments.**

I am trying to solve this question using no numerical methods (like Matlab).

First, I know because the $\operatorname{rank}(M) = 3$, there are three linearly independent column vectors in $M$. I don't want to ref the matrix $M$ and find the pivot columns, which will give me those column vectors. I need to do this with a more theoretical approach.

I want to express w as a linear combination of all column vectors. If that is true, should I be combining all column vectors ($5$ vectors) or just the linearly independent column vectors ($3$ vectors)

I am stuck and confused. Is there a more theoretical approach to these two questions?

Comment: How do you know that $rk(M) = 3$ ?

Comment: @angryavian, I would not have enough time or availability of a computer to do this numerically or use Gaussian elimination by hand. Using Gaussian Elimination would take forever; would a more theoretical approach exist? Using the concept of Rank or the W vector has 0 in the last row?

Comment: I suspect that if the question is phrased that way, that the rank is less than 3. Can't be 1, so 2 may be it.

Comment: @InfiniteLooper, sorry Rank(M) = 3 is given in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The columns are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so the span of those columns will be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. If you know that the rank of the matrix is $3$, that information is telling you that the subspace is $3$-dimensional, i.e. it's all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so the answer for *any* vector $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is **yes,** it's in the span.

More generally, say if the matrix only had rank $2$, this question amounts to solving a linear system represented by appending the given vector $\mathbf{w}$ as a $6$th column on the right, and asking if the system is consistent (is there a pivot in each of the $3$ rows?), which is a computational task.

Comment: Thanks. So would a set that span(M) be any set of three independent column vectors in M? I know that if we computationally do this and reduce it using Gaussian Elimination, we can look for the column vectors with pivot entries. But I can't use Matlab or such.   Thus, for the answer to (b), can I just state any set of 3 linearly independent column vectors of M is a set that spans (M)?

Comment: For (b), I think the intended answer is to simply say $\text{span}(M) = \mathbb{R}^3$. But "span of 3 linearly independent columns of $M$" is also correct. @user10529827

Comment: Once you know that $rk(M)=3$, there is no need of matlab anymore. You have to deal with a rank 3 matrix, forget of all coefficients.

Comment: @angryavian, so I can confidently conclude that if rank(M) = 3, subspace is R^3. Thus, rank(M) = n, will subspace will always be R^n?

Comment: Yes. The rank of a matrix is the dimension of the span of the matrix, and the span of the matrix is really the span of the column vectors of the matrix. If this rank is maximum (which it is in this case), then it's the entire space $\mathbb{R}^k$, where $k$ is the minimum of the the number of rows and number of columns. In this case, $m = 3 < 5 = n$, so this maximum is indeed $k = m = 3$.